# Where are all these ipfw rules coming from?

Tags: macos, network, imap

Any attempt to connect to a server over port 143 is blocked by the OS. I've verified it's not my connection; other computers on the network can see the port just fine. I've replicated the problem on a different network, as well as both the Ethernet and Wifi interfaces.

On my Macbook, I get this:

```
$ telnet mail.xxxx.com 143
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

$ telnet mail.xxxx.com 110
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to mail.xxxx.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Welcome to MailEnable POP3 Server
```

On another computer on the same network:

```
$ telnet mail.xxxx.com 143
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to mail.xxxx.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK IMAP4rev1 server ready at 07/28/11 19:53:15
```

The problem is due to a lot of extraneous **ipfw** rules:

```
$ sudo ipfw show
00010   1166    210912 allow ip from any to any via lo*
00100      0         0 deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any in
00110      0         0 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8 in
00120      0         0 deny ip from 224.0.0.0/3 to any in
00130      0         0 deny tcp from any to 224.0.0.0/3 in
10010      0         0 check-state
10020    163     12011 deny ip from any to any established in
10030      0         0 deny ip from any to any frag in
20000     14       784 skipto 50000 icmp from any to any out keep-state
20010 227761 225019565 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 80,8080 out setup keep-state
20011   7994   1700223 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 443,8443 out setup keep-state
20020      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 53 out setup keep-state
20020   1359    125457 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 53 out keep-state
20030    150     17801 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 110,993 out setup keep-state
20031      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 25,465,587 out setup keep-state
20040    501     54357 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 22 out setup keep-state
20050      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 21 out setup keep-state
20060      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 123 out setup keep-state
20060     12       912 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 123 out keep-state
20070      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 113 out setup keep-state
20070      0         0 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 113 out keep-state
20080      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 194 out setup keep-state
20080      0         0 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 194 out keep-state
20090      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 137-139,445 out setup keep-state
20090    214     28854 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 137-139,445 out keep-state
20100      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 1194 out setup keep-state
20100      0         0 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 1194 out keep-state
20110      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 111,2049 out setup keep-state
20110      0         0 skipto 50000 udp from any to any dst-port 111,2049 out keep-state
20120      0         0 skipto 50000 tcp from any to any dst-port 6881-6999 out setup keep-state
30000      0         0 allow tcp from any to me dst-port 22 in setup keep-state
30010      0         0 allow udp from any to me dst-port 67,68 in keep-state
30020      0         0 allow icmp from 192.168.0.2 to any in keep-state
40000   1284    289790 deny ip from any to any
50000 238005 226947953 allow ip from any to any
65535     25      7914 allow ip from any to any
```

I cannot find where these settings are coming from, disabling the firewall has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared them out with:

```
$ sudo ipfw -f flush
```

But this is only a temporary fix, and I have no idea where these rules are coming from.

I've discovered that disabling the ruleset they belong to lasts longer:

```
$ sudo ipfw set disable 0
```

But they still get re-enabled after a reboot.

Comment: I upgraded from 10.6 to Lion; I don't have any of these in my table.

Comment: @NReilingh this was so weird. It was blocking my network printer as well. Still have no idea where they came from.

Comment: @NReilingh I even did a fresh install of Lion, wiped my partition first.

Comment: The ipfw rule list isn't even preserved across reboots, so it must've been something installed on the computer, running at startup, setting up the rule list. Wiping and reinstalling *will* fix that...

Comment: @Gordon You're right, a flush is only a temporary measure. Where could rules be stored? I don't have `/etc/firewall.conf` and I can't find a plist for it.

Answer (score -1):

They are coming from /etc/ipfilter/*

Comment: Nope. OSX doesn't have /etc/ipfilter